# Scan dotcode in react native qrcode-scanner

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can we scan `DotCode` in qrcode scanner?

This are the type in react native qrcode scanner

```
aztec: any,
code128: any, 
code39: any,
code39mod43: any,
code93: any,
ean13: any,
ean8: any,
pdf417: any,
qr: any,
upce: any,
interleaved2of5: any,
itf14: any,
datamatrix: any
```

Can we add `Dotcode` in that?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure. You can add the implementation by yourself.